# Wanting to create a specific layout in JFrame (JAVA)

Tags: java, jframe

So I'm procrastinating studying for finals and thought I should make a simple game instead after taking an intro to Java class. We briefly learned how to use JFrames so I wanted to use this for my game. I'm making a simple clicker game similar to cookie clicker or any game in that same genre. Right now my GUI looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ootnJ.png). I want my GUI to look similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOpsZ.jpg) where the menu buttons are on different sides of a central button. I tried to use different layout managers and none of them worked for what I was doing. I have tried flow layout, box layout, and grid layout. The grid one got me the closest but still didn't work well since everything was the same size and were just a grid, so I couldn't have that central button. Does anyone have any tips for me?

This is my launcher class

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game theGame = new Game();
        theGame.setSize(650,500);
        theGame.setVisible(true);
        theGame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        theGame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
                theGame.createSaveFile();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my game class

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Timer;

    public class Game extends JFrame {
        Buying buy = new Buying();
        //creates an instance of SMUQuest
        private int roundNumber = 1;

        //widgets
        JLabel money;
        JButton clicker;
        JButton upgradeClicker;
        JButton firstPurchase;
        JButton secondPurchase;
        JButton thirdPurchase;
        JButton fourthPurchase;
        JButton fifthPurchase;
        JButton sixthPurchase;
        JLabel firstPurchase$PS;
        JLabel firstPurchasePrice;
        JLabel firstPerSecond;



        public Game() {
            super("Clicker Game");
            checkSaveFile();
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            clicker = new JButton("CLICK ME FOR 1 POINT!");
            add(clicker);
            clicker.addActionListener(new MyInner());
            upgradeClicker = new JButton("Add 1 to your clicking power for $" + buy.getClickerPrice());
            add(upgradeClicker);
            upgradeClicker.addActionListener(new MyInner());
            money = new JLabel("" + buy.getMoney());
            add(money);
            firstPurchasePrice = new JLabel("" + buy.getFirstBuyPrice());
            add(firstPurchasePrice);
            firstPurchase = new JButton("First Property!");
            add(firstPurchase);
            firstPurchase.addActionListener(new MyInner()); 
            firstPurchase$PS = new JLabel("" + buy.getFirstBuy$PS());
            add(firstPurchase$PS);



            //timer to add money every second
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   buy.moneyPS();
                   money.setText("You have $" + buy.getMoney());
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
        }

        private class MyInner implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == firstPurchase) {
                    if(buy.getMoney() >= buy.getFirstBuyPrice()) {
                    buy.subtractMoney(buy.getFirstBuyPrice());
                    buy.setFirstBuy$PS(1);
                    buy.setFirstBuyPrice(2);
                    firstPurchase$PS.setText("$" + buy.getFirstBuy$PS());       
                    firstPurchasePrice.setText("$" + buy.getFirstBuyPrice());   
                    money.setText("You have $" + buy.getMoney());
                    }
                }
                if (e.getSource() == clicker) {
                    buy.addMoney(buy.getClickerStrength());
                    money.setText("You have $" + buy.getMoney());
                }
                if (e.getSource() == upgradeClicker) {
                    if(buy.getMoney() >= buy.getClickerPrice()) {
                    buy.subtractMoney(buy.getClickerPrice());
                    buy.setClickerPrice();
                    upgradeClicker.setText("Add 1 to your clicking power for $" + buy.getClickerPrice());
                    buy.setClickerStrength();
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        public void checkSaveFile() {
            File inputFile = new File("SaveGame.txt");
            try {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
                    int line = input.nextInt();
                    if(line > 0) 
                        buy.setMoney(line);
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException exp) {
                System.out.println("File not Found Exception. Make sure the input file exists.");
            }
        }
        public void createSaveFile() {
            File outputFile = new File("SaveGame.txt");//creates a new file
            try {
                PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(outputFile); 
                pWriter.println(buy.getMoney());
                pWriter.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException exp) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my class for setting values to variables and such

```
public class Buying {
            private int firstBuy$PS;
            private int firstBuyPrice;
            private int money = 1;
            private int clickerStrength = 1;
            private int clickerPrice =10;

            public int getFirstBuy$PS() {
                return firstBuy$PS;
            }

            public void setFirstBuy$PS(int x) {
                firstBuy$PS += x;
            }

            public int getFirstBuyPrice() {
                return firstBuyPrice;
            }

            public void setFirstBuyPrice(int x) {
                firstBuyPrice += x;
            }
            public void moneyPS() {
                money += getFirstBuy$PS();
            }
            public int getMoney() {
                return money;
            }
            public void subtractMoney(int x) {
                money -= x;
            }
            public void addMoney(int x) {
                money += x;
            }
            public void setMoney(int x) {
                money = x;
            }
            public void setClickerStrength() {
                clickerStrength += 1; 
            }
            public int getClickerStrength() {
                return clickerStrength;
            }
            public int getClickerPrice() {
                return clickerPrice;
            }
            public void setClickerPrice() {
                clickerPrice*=1.2323452;
            }
        }
```

Edit: Put code in the question and not a link to my Github

Comment: Copy and paste your code into your question then highlight it and press `ctrl+k`

Comment: Also, you'll need to be somewhat more specific.  Are you only trying to make your layout look different?  Which layout managers have you used?  Which one got you the closest?  Do you have a preference for a particular layout manager, and just can't get it tow work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems you are just begining to play with GUIs i strongly suggest you use a GUI manager like swing.

Other than that all i saw in your code is you creating the components and adding them to your layout without telling the program where to put them. That is the reason your game look like that.

I think using a GridPane can totally do the job. My only hint is that a grid definitely has a place for a central button. Look at the image of how you want your game to look and try to see a grid there.

More than this and i think i would spoon feed you too much and that isnt good.

Comment: Thank you for your hints @BarriaKarl. I definitely don't want you to spoon me any code I want to figure this out for myself. I will look into swing and GridPane. I noticed the grid layout of the picture I attached I just need to figure out how to layout now. Time to start learning some more stuff haha :)